# Correct usage of urllib2 open() in a loop

Tags: python

I have a loop which aims at making URL requests and reading the results. When the requests are "simple", the code works fine. However, when a request requires more time from the server, then my program hangs forever. It seems that it tries to process all the requests simultaneously, though I don't understand why. I've tried studying documentation for `opener.open(url).read()` but have not succeeded in finding the answer to my question. I will appreciate your help.

Here is my code for Python 2.7:

```
username = 'the_username'
password = 'the_password'
corpus_name = 'the_corpusname'
root_url = 'root_url'
base_url = '%s/bonito/run.cgi/' % root_url
method = 'view'
attrs = dict(corpname=corp, q='', pagesize=1, format='json',async=0)

# authentication
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_data = urllib.urlencode({ 'username' : username,
                                'password' : password,
                                'submit' : 'ok',
                              })
data = opener.open('%s/login/' % root_url)
data = opener.open('%s/login/' % root_url, login_data)

pattern = r"[\n\r]"
pattern_re = re.compile(pattern)

with open('input.txt', "r") as f_in, open('output.txt', "a") as f_out: 
    for line in f_in:
        line = pattern_re.sub("",line) # removing \n or \r at the end
        query = "[lemma_lc=\"" + line + "\"&pos=\"N\"]"
        attrs['q'] = 'q' + query
        encoded_attrs = urllib.quote(simplejson.JSONEncoder().encode(attrs))
        url = base_url + method + '?json=%s' % encoded_attrs
        file1 = opener.open(url)
        data = file1.read()
        file1.close()
        json_obj = simplejson.loads(data)
        f_out.write(line + '\t' + str(json_obj.get('concsize', '0')) + '\n')
        time.sleep(4)
```

Comment: Even if your code is not very Pythonic, I suspect that the actual problem lies in the (not shown) *processing data*  zone. But you really should use `with open('input.txt', "r") as f_in, open('output.txt', "a") as f_out: for line in f_in: #creating a url...` with context managers and file iterators...

Comment: Dear Serge, thank you for your suggestion. I've made the appropriate changes to the code. However, the loop gets executed for 9 times and then the program hangs forever (there are 15 lines in the input file). Any ideas? I've updated the post to show the full code.